# What has happened to the latest version of Vice C64 emulator?

Tags: emulation

i just installed Vice C64 emulator, put the roms in the correct folders, and ran it. it runs at 5fps now on my pc, while it used to be full speed (well above 30fps) on the previous version of Xubuntu (18.04, i now have 20.04lts). i tried changing options in settings, but to my avail nothing can speed emulation up. i changed opengl to cairo and back, nothing. it stays at 5 fps. so i decided to remove Vice, and try the flathub package. i removed vice, and installed the flatpak version from the flathpak website. same result. can anyone please tell me what i have to do to speed vice emulation up, it used to be +30fps, instead of 4/5 fps now.

Answer (score 1):

i found the culprit. it seems that the vice commodore 64 emulator from the synaptic package manager AND the software store (the same i guess) are different than the one from the snapstore. so i deleted vice c64 with use of synaptic package manager completely. then i went to https://snapcraft.io/vice-jz and i clicked install with snap store, and this fixed the problem. this version of vice hits 50+fps on any of my pcs, and is being supplied out-of-the-box with all the neccesary system roms like kernal, chargen, basic etc. no hassle with system roms required.